# Azure MobileApp : InvokeApiAsync failing with InvalidOperationException

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying out the Azure Mobile app and the recently released SDKs
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-mobile-apps-november-2015-update/

I created the service and the starter Todo app was working fine.  I then added facebook authentication and that worked too. I also wanted to get some additional FB info from the service , so based on a solution and the sample app on github , I added a new api

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/2d2901ed5207f0ba6698660eb4ee568a63f18581/samples/SampleApp/Controllers/SecuredController.cs

**Server side code**

```
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<JObject> GetIdentity()
    {
        FacebookCredentials fb = await this.User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>(this.Request);
        var result = new JObject();
        if (fb != null)
        {
            var accessToken = fb.AccessToken;
            result.Add("facebook", await GetProviderInfo("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<JToken> GetProviderInfo(string url)
    {
        var c = new HttpClient();
        var resp = await c.GetAsync(url);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return JToken.Parse(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }

}
```

**Client Side Code in Android project**

```
var user = await TodoItemManager.Instance.ClientInstance.LoginAsync(Forms.Context, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
var info = await TodoItemManager.Instance.ClientInstance.InvokeApiAsync("GetIdentity", null, HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

**The LoginAsync succeeds and I get the UserId and Token, but InvokeApiAsync fails with following exception**

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext () [0x0022f] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-26 19:09:10.897 I/mono-stdout( 3514):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext () [0x0022f] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
11-26 19:09:10.898 I/mono-stdout( 3514): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-26 19:09:10.898 I/mono-stdout( 3514):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
11-26 19:09:10.899 I/mono-stdout( 3514):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
11-26 19:09:10.900 I/mono-stdout( 3514):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:124 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext () [0x0010d] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post only relevant code and not link to external code sources. Also, please format the error message properly.

Comment: I think the authentication header might be missing when you call "GetIdentity" . Can you use Fiddler to check that value? I think you can configure Fiddler to be a proxy of your Android emulator. Do you have `[MobileAppController]` attribute on your controller?

Comment: To confirm whether you are missing the authentication token on http request header or not, you can remove `[Authorize]` from ` GetIdentity()` method and re-deploy your service and see whether you got the same error or different error.

Comment: Are you having issue at `GetProviderInfo()` method? What permission did you set? You can use " Graph API Explorer" https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to generate the token  with the permissions you selected. and then you can test your code with that token.

Comment: hey Michael, thanks for the suggestions..
I had `[MobileAppController]` attribute on the controller. I even tried removing all authentication. Basically created a new service and just added a new `ApiController` with one `GetIdentity` methods which just returns a string and got the same `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` error. Not having much luck with fiddler either. I proxied my android device thru fiddler. I see traces for all apps. But dont see anything for the mobile app .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in my project, using the new Azure App Service sample projects. I was simply trying to retrieve data from an Azure db using my own model classes, not doing authentication like you.

Here's the error:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Turns out, in my mobile server project, I had a model defined as `CorporateEvent`, and in my client project, I had the same model defined as `CorporateEventModel`. Once I renamed the model in my client project to `CorporateEvent`, the error went away and I was able to access the database.

Hope that helps.